# Digital Ocean CyberPanel (on Ubuntu 18.04): ACME certificates blocked forbidden - 283 Failed to obtain SSL for domain. [issueSSLForDomain]

Tags: ssl, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, litespeed, acme

I installed a brand new DigitalOcean droplet using a marketplace base (so on paper everything should be OK out of the box).
When trying to issue certificates, i am getting this error:

```
[11.13.2019_04-48-28] /root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d thehouseinkorazim.co.il -d www.thehouseinkorazim.co.il --cert-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/thehouseinkorazim.co.il/cert.pem --key-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/thehouseinkorazim.co.il/privkey.pem --fullchain-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/thehouseinkorazim.co.il/fullchain.pem -w /home/thehouseinkorazim.co.il/public_html --force
[11.13.2019_04-48-28] [Errno 2] No such file or directory [Failed to obtain SSL. [obtainSSLForADomain]]
[11.13.2019_04-48-28] 283 Failed to obtain SSL for domain. [issueSSLForDomain]
[11.13.2019_04-48-34] Trying to obtain SSL for: thehouseinkorazim.co.il and: www.thehouseinkorazim.co.il
```

I checked and UFW is not installed.
I do have a network firewall but it is the same one as another droplet that does allow for certificates (same rules) so I think it is not the cause.

I searched all the answers online and no luck.
I even installed certboot to manually issue certificate but same error (i did it because I know you need to register initially to get certificates and I haven't so I thought it was the cause).

Any ideas? Thanks!

update: i did a clean droplet again, this is the issue without anything I did manually:

```
Cannot issue SSL. Error message: ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/lsws/admin/conf/cert/admin.crt': No such file or directory ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/lsws/admin/conf/cert/admin.key': No such file or directory 0,283 Failed to obtain SSL for domain. [issueSSLForDomain]
```

I checked and there is no folder "cert" under "conf" in the path written above.

Comment: FYI, new version(1.9.2) is now on the marketplace. Feel free to give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an known SSL issue on recent version due to some environment/code changing. We already aware it and submitted a new version which has that issue fixed included. Please give it a day or two and you should be able to launch the new version from marketplace which comes with CyberPanel v1.9.2.

Best